# total not updated after custom shipping price applied

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I am changing shipping price on the fly but it doesn't update cart total as it should.

Here is my code.

Observer event i m using `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after`

code from observer.

```
public function checkshipping(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    //echo Mage::helper('shippingoptions')->getSaturday_delivery(); exit;
    if(/* Mage::helper('shippingoptions')->getSaturday_delivery() */Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getSaturdayDelivery()){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
        $price = 20;
        $address = $observer->getQuoteAddress();
        $quote = $address->getQuote();
        $address->setCollectShippingRates(false);
        $rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
        ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
        foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
            foreach ($carrier as $rate) {                   
                if($rate->getCode()=='fedex_PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT'){
                    $finalPrice = $rate->getPrice()+$price;
                    /* $rate->setPrice($finalPrice);
                    $rate->save(); */
                }
            }
        }
        $title = $address->getShippingDescription();
        $address->setShippingDescription($title.' - Saturday Delivery');
        $address->setShippingAmount($finalPrice);
        $address->setBaseShippingAmount($finalPrice);
        //$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

        $address->save();
    }

}
```

when i enable `$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()` it goes to infinite loop. Have also tried `before` event but no luck.

Please guide.